# Makefile as root

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, scheduling

Good evening everyone,

I was able to create a code to launch real-time tasks, I used sched_setscheduler to modify the type of scheduler and it requires to be root to start program execution.
All is fine when I used the command lines, but now I want to run my project with makefile under eclipse, I was able to create the makefile, but my problem that I could not make my code executable as an instance using the makefile

So my question: how to run my makefile project  which is created under eclipse as administrator, is there an instruction to add in my makefile file to do that?

Comment: either `runas` or `sudo` depending on OS.

Comment: Yes `sudo`to indicate the root, but where should I add it? in makefile or where? because when I run my project using the makefile it shows an error in the console and it asks to be root!! I use linux operating system

Comment: Add on the commands in the Makefile that need to run as root.  Also update the /etc/sudoers file to add the specific commands.

Comment: all the commands in my makefile must be running as root, should I put sudo at the beginning of makefile??

Comment: *Every* command? Even building and linking it?

Comment: Here is my makefile `prod:  product.c main.c product.h
  gcc -o prod -O3 product.c main.c


prod.db: product.c main.c product.h
 
  gcc -o prod.db -g -O3 product.c main.c
`

Comment: these commands must be executed as root in terminal, but i want to use it in my  C project (using eclipse), in other words makefile must be used in eclipse as root... how can i implement my makefile in this case?? I hope that I have well expressed my problem